# "A 10 hour course" - Why not "hours"

Tags: singular-vs-plural, plural-forms

I came across this example written by a native English teacher: "The student followed a 10 hour English course."

I was curious to know if "hours" would also be valid here, and if there's a nuance etc.

Thanks.